# Getting textarea value with jquery doesnt work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, textarea

Reading with val() doesn't work and I'm getting back only an empty result. How can I read the textarea for updating a db with ajax?

```
var k = jQuery.noConflict();
k(document).ready(function(){  
  k('.portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle').on('keyup', function(){
    var message = k('#gallery_images_comment').val();
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

My html code with the textare looks like this:

```
<div class="portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle">

    <textarea name="comment" id="gallery_images_comment" form="usrform">This is the text loaded</textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: why not bind the keyup to the textarea itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must define somewhere `k` is equivalent to `$` before use it.

```js
var k = $;
k('.portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle').find('#gallery_images_comment').on('keyup', function(){
var message = k(this).val();
console.log(message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle">
  <textarea name="comment" id="gallery_images_comment" form="usrform">This is the text loaded</textarea>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your first code worked. k is from var k = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: That was your first code and it's working:  k('.portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle').find('#gallery_images_comment').on('keyup', function() {
  var message = k(this).val();
  console.log(message);
});

Comment: Ok glad to help. I revert my edit as per your comment. :)

Comment: If you are binding the keyup to the textarea, you may as well just use `this.value` - little bit more efficient than doing a selector and then doing `.val()` on that

Answer (score 0):

I dont know where the `k` was coming from but try to use `$` instead

```js
$('.portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle').on('keyup', function(){
var message = $('#gallery_images_comment').val();
console.log(message);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="portfolio_classic_icon_content_middle">
    <textarea name="comment" id="gallery_images_comment" form="usrform">This is the text loaded</textarea>
</div>
```